# awk group year and month from date in col1 and sum of the group in col2

Tags: text-processing, awk

Any ideas how to group and sum data on the below with the command line script?

```
2018-02-01  10
2018-02-03  12
2018-03-01   1
2018-03-01  12
2018-04-12   9 
2019-01-12 213
```

expected result from the above data set

```
2018-02  22
2018-03  13
2018-04   9
2019-01 213
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$ awk '{a[substr($0,0,7)]+=$2}END{for(b in a){print b,a[b]}}' myfile
2018-02 22
2019-01 213
2018-03 13
2018-04 9
$
```

For sorted, add `sort`

```
$ awk '{a[substr($0,0,7)]+=$2}END{for(b in a){print b,a[b]}}' myfile | sort
2018-02 22
2018-03 13
2018-04 9
2019-01 213
$
```

Comment: With GNU awk, you can sort by adding `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"` to the start of the END block. [Documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` approach:

```
$ awk -F'[- ]' '{a[$1"-"$2]+=$NF}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file | sort
2018-02 22
2019-01 213
2018-03 13
2018-04 0
```

Alternatively, Perl:

```
$ perl -lne '/(.*)-.+ (\d+)/; $k{$1}+=$2 }{ print "$_ $k{$_}" for sort keys(%k)' file 
2018-02 22
2018-03 13
2018-04 9
2019-01 213
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can sort the output without using external binaries like `sort`:

```
awk '{arr[substr($0,0,7)]+=$2}END{a=asorti(arr,sort); for(i=1;i<=a;i++) print sort[i], arr[sort[i]]}' infile.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below method  and its working fine

```
for i in `awk '{if (!seen[$1]++){print substr($1,1,8)}}' filename |sort | uniq`; do echo $i;sed -n '/'$i'/p' filename| awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$2} END{print sum}' ;done| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
2018-02- 22
2018-03- 13
2018-04- 9
2019-01- 213
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`csvsql`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/scripts/csvsql.html) from `csvkit`:

```bsh
csvsql -d' ' -H --tables file --query "
  select substr(a,1,7) as the_date,sum(b)
  from file
  group by the_date;
" <(tr -s ' ' < file)
```

Output:

```
the_date,sum(b)
2018-02,22
2018-03,13
2018-04,9
2019-01,213
```